# Switch from webRequest to DeclarativeNetRequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension, version, manifest

I want to move from MV2 to MV3. My current problem is that I dont know how to switch from webRequest to DeclarativeNetRequest.

I have to handle web requests and check if they are complete or have an error.

My code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(webCompleteOrError,
    {
        urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    });

chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(webCompleteOrError,
    {
        urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    });
```

Also I need something similar with responseHeaders.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(handleHeaders, { urls: ['<all_urls>'], tabId: sender.tab.id, types: ['sub_frame', 'main_frame'] }, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

handleHeaders function i just check to make sure there are no x frame options or csp and remove them if they exist.

```
var handleHeaders = function(details)
{
    if (details.tabId != global_pinger_value && details.tabId != -1)
        return { responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders };

    // make sure there are no x frame options
    for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; i++)
    {
        var headers = details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase();
        if (headers == 'x-frame-options' || headers == 'frame-options')
        {
            details.responseHeaders.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; i++)
    {
        var headers = details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase();
        if (headers == 'content-security-policy')
        {
            details.responseHeaders.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    return {
        responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders
    };
};

I can't find a way to do this.
```

Comment: The first two webRequest listeners are compatible with ManifestV3 because they don't use `blocking` mode. For onHeadersReceived it depends on what handleHeaders does, so you must show its code.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm ! I have updated the question with the function that is used to handle headers from the response. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: You can delete headers in DNR using the [remove operation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-ModifyHeaderInfo:~:text=header%22%3A%20%22h1%22%2C%20%22operation%22%3A%20%22remove). To limit to a tabId use [tabIds](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#property-RuleCondition-tabIds) condition.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the response. I'll see if this works.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh one more thing. Is it possible to run some function when using declarativeNetRequest, as we did when we were using webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(some_function...)?

Comment: No. You can use webRequest for that in case there's no `blocking` mode.

Comment: @wOxxOm And if there is blocking mode?

Comment: Then there's no solution.